# How to Access list of JSON objects

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net

I am trying to get the "name" and "value" attribute from the JSON file which i am loading externally.

I tried accessing the list Valuestore and I am returned with an error.

"""Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ExternalJSON.Form1+Valuestore]' because the type requires a JSON array """"

How can i access the list value store and print the name and value in the listview.

My Code

```
    public class Value
    {
        public string value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Valuestore
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public Value value { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public string version { get; set; }
        public List<Valuestore> Valuestore { get; set; }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var json = File.ReadAllText(".....\\static_settings");

        var settingsNamelst1 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
        var settingsNamelst2 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Valuestore>>(json);

        foreach (var lst in settingsNamelst2)
        {
            listView1.Items.Add(lst.name);
        }

    }
```

And my JSON file is

```
{
    "version": "2",
    "valuestore": [
        {
            "name": "abcd1",
            "type": "string",
            "value": {
                "value": "0002"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "abcd2",
            "type": "string",
            "value": {
                "value": "001"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: `foreach (var lst in settingsNamelst1.Valuestore)`

Comment: `and I am returned with an error.` what error? Include it in your question.

Comment: The error is caused by `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Valuestore>>(json);`. Remove that line and use what @EZI suggested instead

Comment: Perfect. Works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing you can do is to deserialize it dynamically, and acces the objects over dynamic properties.

```
var json = @"{
                        ""version"": ""2"",
                        ""valuestore"": [
                            {
                                ""name"": ""abcd1"",
                                ""type"": ""string"",
                                ""value"": {
                                    ""value"": ""0002""
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                ""name"": ""abcd2"",
                                ""type"": ""string"",
                                ""value"": {
                                    ""value"": ""001""
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }";

        dynamic jsonTemp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
        foreach (var i in jsonTemp.valuestore)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("name: {0}, value: {1} \n", i.name, i.value.value);
        }
```

Comment: Selecting this answer. Crisp and clear solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Your `settingsNamelst1` property is already deserialized and contains the `Valuestore`, no need to de-serialize it again:

```
var settingsNamelst1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
foreach (var item in settingsNamelst1.Valuestore)
{
    listView1.Items.Add(item.name);
}
```

The reason you're seeing the exception is because your JSON schema doesn't match `List<Valuestore>`, it matches your `RootObject`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. How can i access value attribute. For example var settingsNamelst1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<list<value>.(json); Because it give the same error for value

Comment: @raj3209812 Come on, don't be so lazy. VS will help you

Comment: Ok. Got the hint from Nikola.Lukovic answer.

Comment: value.value made the difference. Thanks every one